# passing card holders name in create customer source

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

Hi I have been searching for 2 days and it is so strange I am not sure why the stripe development team do not properly clarify the things I have been trying to add card by the customer but there is not way I can attach the card holder's name below is what I used

```
$intent = \Stripe\customer::createSource($customerID, array( 
            'source' => $token,
            'name' => 'John Doe'
        ));
```

by using above i got an error of Received unknown parameter: name
here is how I am creating the token

```
var elements = stripe.elements();

var style = {
    base: {
        fontWeight: 400,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif',
        fontSize: '16px',
        lineHeight: '1.4',
        color: '#555',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        '::placeholder': {
            color: '#888',
        },
    },
    invalid: {
        color: '#eb1c26',
    }
};

var cardElement = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    style: style
});
cardElement.mount('#card_number');

var exp = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
    'style': style
});
exp.mount('#card_expiry');

var cvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
    'style': style
});
cvc.mount('#card_cvc');

// Validate input of the card elements
var resultContainer = document.getElementById('paymentResponse');
cardElement.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if (event.error) {
        resultContainer.innerHTML = '<p>'+event.error.message+'</p>';
    } else {
        resultContainer.innerHTML = '';
    }
});

// Get payment form element
var form = document.getElementById('paymentFrm');

// Create a token when the form is submitted.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    createToken();
});

// Create single-use token to charge the user
function createToken() {
    stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            // Inform the user if there was an error
            resultContainer.innerHTML = '<p>'+result.error.message+'</p>';
        } else {
            // Send the token to your server
            stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
    });
}

// Callback to handle the response from stripe
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    
    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
}
```

In their documentation they have provided the information as child elements as parameters

source
REQUIRED
A token, like the ones returned by Stripe.js. Stripe will automatically validate the card.

Hide child parameters
source.object
REQUIRED
The type of payment source. Should be card.

source.number
REQUIRED
The card number, as a string without any separators.

source.exp_month
REQUIRED
Two-digit number representing the card's expiration month.

source.exp_year
REQUIRED
Two- or four-digit number representing the card's expiration year.

source.name
optional
Cardholder's full name.

But I mean come on why they haven't informed about providing card holder's name they should provide us the option thought can any one help me out to let me know how can i pass card holder's name please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the card holder name when you create the token client-side here using StripeJS. Specifically, you pass a `data` object to `stripe.createToken`: https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement#stripe_create_token-data-name

````
stripe.createToken(cardElement, {
  name: nameVariable
  });```
````

Comment: You rock but still I noticed stripe is a big headache their documentation is very very low they do not provide proper information I mean I am not sure how do i pass name via creating token

Comment: Edited above to include code snippet